# Get multiple php data via json ajax with the same name

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm working on a live search and i need to transfer php data to ajax using json, but the problem is i can't pass an array contain 2 or more identical values, this is the php code:

```
<?php
    class search{
        public function gettingvalues($search_value){
            require_once('db_conx.php');
            $dir = "http://localhost/usersimage/";
            $sql = "SELECT name,img,username FROM users WHERE username like '$search_value%' || name like '$search_value%'";
            $query = mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
            if ($query) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $img = $row['img'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $json = array('img' => $img, 'name' => $name, 'username' => $username);
                        echo json_encode($json);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And this is the index code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
        require('search.php');
        $search = new search;
        $search->gettingvalues($_POST['data']);
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        die();
    }
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').keyup(function(){
            var value= $('input').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: {data: value},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(json_data){
                    $('#feedback').html(json_data.name);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="looking for?">
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

So, if my array contain 2 or more identical names ajax wont get any data back, I hope someone have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create array with all results in your search function and then in ajax response loop results to get all names and print it separated by comma.

**Search function**

```
<?php
    class search{
        public function gettingvalues($search_value){
            require_once('db_conx.php');
            $dir = "http://localhost/usersimage/";
            $sql = "SELECT name,img,username FROM users WHERE username like '$search_value%' || name like '$search_value%'";
            $query = mysqli_query($conx,$sql);
            $results = []; //<!---
            if ($query) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        $img = $row['img'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $json = array('img' => $img, 'name' => $name, 'username' => $username);
                        $results[] = $json;  //<!---
                    }
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($results); //<!---
        }
    }
?>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').keyup(function(){
            var value= $('input').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "",
                data: {data: value},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(json_data) {
                  var names = [];
                  $.each(json_data, function(index, element) {
                    names.push(element.name)
                  })
                  $('#feedback').html(names.join(','));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="looking for?">
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $img = $row['img'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $username = $row['username'];
                    $json = array('img' => $img, 'name' => $name, 'username' => $username);
                    echo json_encode($json);
                }
```

To:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $img = $row['img'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $json[] = array('img' => $img, 'name' => $name, 'username' => $username);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Inside your response for jQuery, retrieve your json data by looping it. Make sure to use var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( json_data ); before looping

Comment: Yeah it work like that, but i want to get all the data from database even the identical data.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. May be this is what you want to know?
Change like '$search_value%' to  like '%$search_value%', this will check if that string is anywhere inside the column field. If this doesn't help can you give more info?